# Searching in multiple folders for specific file if it exists or not using Wildcard

Tags: loops, wildcard, glob, subdirectory, os.walk

I've searched through web and asked people about my "simple" problem, but I got no satisfactoy answer.

My problem is following:

I'm comparing data from Exhange (in form of excel files, that are saved in some folders) and data in my system (SQL query from database). I'm designing a tool that compares data FROM - TO specific DATE. All my exchange data filenames are based on specific date format, some string and excel file format varies (sometimes .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm).

Obviously what I need to do is to write a loop to search for needed files from "FROM" date to "TO" date. Let's take a period from 7th July 2020 to 13th July 2020. **Let's say, that files for 11th July 2020 are missing**. Bear in mind, that my files are stored in some location with **multiple subfolders** named by MONTH etc.

Example:

```
C:\Users\VB\Desktop\VB\python\05
C:\Users\VB\Desktop\VB\python\06
C:\Users\VB\Desktop\VB\python\07
```

Here are some examples of my filenames:

```
07.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
07.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx
08.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
08.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx
09.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
09.07.2020 - WorstScore.xls
10.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
10.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsm
12.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
12.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx
```

My basic code looks like this:

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta

startD = date(2020,7,10)
day= timedelta(days=1)
EndD = date(2020,7,13)

folder = 'C:\Users\VB\Desktop\VB\python'

while startD <= EndD:
    
    date=(startD.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
    file = date + '-BestScore'
    file2 = date + '-Worstscore'

    **code IF file or file2 is found ---> do something **
    ** ELSE IF file or file2 is not found ---> print(file or file2 not found)
```

Problem occurs because I must **use Wildcards** and need to search through **multiple folders** (sometimes I need to comapare data for few months backward, so searching in different folder is a must).

I have tried to use different functions for looping through multiple folder:

- os.walk()
- glob.glob()
- glob2.iglob()

but none of them works the way I want. While looping, these functions check each file for wildcard name and obviously return "else if" statement for above for EACH filename that is not exactly named:

```
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
no file for 20200713
```

I don't need to check each file if it is the right one, I just want to receive results like this:

```
found 07.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
found 07.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx
found 08.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
found 08.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx
found 09.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
found 09.07.2020 - WorstScore.xls
found 10.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
found 10.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsm
NOT found 11.07.2020 - Bestscore
NOT found 11.07.2020 - Worstscore
found 12.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
found 12.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx
```

To sum up, I need a solution to search in multiple subfolders with Wildcard* and NOT to check every file with IF statement.

I'm learning python for few months and I think this should not be a great problem to solve, but I'm kinda confused about it.
Solving this problem would complete my project, since everything else is already working :)

I would be very glad for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you repost your own question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045553/ ) , when you accepted an answer and thus marked it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather vague: it would be nice if you could provide some more details on the file system structure..

Regardless, I interpret you question as the following: Given a directory to search in and two dates (start and finish), you want to search for two different files (BestScore and WorstScore) within those dates. If they exist, do something, else, print warning.

Example:

- Start date: 07.07.2020
- End state: 08.07.2020
- Search dir: ~/some/dir
- Allowed file-extensions: xls, xlsm, xlsx

This means that we are looking for **four** files:

- ~/some/dir/ ..... /07.07.2020 - BestScore.xls
- ~/some/dir/ ..... /07.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx
- ~/some/dir/ ..... /08.07.2020 - BestScore.xlsm
- ~/some/dir/ ..... /08.07.2020 - WorstScore.xlsx

.. and any of them may, or may not, exist within some sub directory of `~/some/dir`. We are uninterested in any other files from other dates regardless of their existance or not.

First, we'll need some helper functions. We start off with whatever you want to do to existing files, here represented by a `print`,

```py
def do_something_with(file_path):
  # do something with file ..
  print("doing something with '%s' .." % file_path)
```

A function for determining if a directory entry is a file and of the correct file type,

```py
import os
def is_xls_file(file_path):
  return (os.path.isfile(file_path) and (
    file_path.endswith(".xls") or
    file_path.endswith(".xlsm") or
    file_path.endswith(".xlsx")))
```

A function for creating a dict of the files we are searching for,

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
def files_to_find(start_date, end_date, filenames):
  files = {}
  d = start_date
  while d != end_date:
    for fn in filenames:
      files["%s - %s" % (d.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"), fn)] = None
    d += timedelta(days=1)
  return files
```

And then the actually search function: We perform a `os.walk()`, iterating over all files and subdirectories. If we find the files we're looking for, we store their paths in the `files_to_find`dictionary.

```py
def find_files(files_to_find, search_dir):
  for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(search_dir):
    for f in files:
      for ftf in files_to_find:
        # add .lower() for case-insensitivity
        if ftf.lower() in f.lower() and is_xls_file(os.path.join(dirpath,f)):
          files_to_find[ftf] = os.path.join(dirpath,f)
  return files_to_find
```

We may iterate over the `file_to_find` dictionary and perform whatever operations needed on the files that existed and print a warning for those that did not,

```py
startD = date(2020,7,10)
EndD = date(2020,7,13)
filenames = ["bestscore", "worstscore"] # the search is case-insensitve
search_dir = "./fold1/fold2"

to_find = files_to_find(startD, EndD, filenames)
found = find_files(to_find, search_dir)

for f,abs_path in found.items():
  if abs_path is None:
    print("Was unable to find '%s'" % f)
  else:
    do_something_with(abs_path)
```

Below is a screen shot of an example run with results from the displayed file system, using the input from above. As explained earlier, the script will in *this example* be searching for **six** files (i.e. the Best- and WorstScore) for each date. Thus, it prints *exactly* six events, one for each file: did it find it, or not..

[image: example run]

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate your detailed explanation, thanks. I confess that my problem description is rather vague than clear.
In the meantime I have figured out how to handle my problem, see below:
With help of my IT collague we found a solution using **glob.glob function**.

```
import glob
from datetime import timedelta, date

startD = date(2020,7,10)
day= timedelta(days=1)
EndD = date(2020,7,15)

path = '//some folder'
#print(path)

while startD <= EndD:
    
    date=(startD.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    file = date + '_best_score*'  # wildcard because of various extension
    file2 = date + '_worst_score*' ## wildcard because of various extension
    result = glob.glob(f'{path}/**/{file}', recursive=True) # search through all subfolders of "path"
    result2 = glob.glob(f'{path}/**/{file2}', recursive=True) # search through all subfolders of "path"
  
    if result or result2:
        print("found file", file)
        print("found file", file2)

    else:
        print("missing", file)
        print("missing", file2)

    startD += day
```

Using /**/ does the magic here I think, because I have many subfolders that are named differently.
This code work only if both files are found, so we modified if statement. As glob.glob function returns two possible lists, we join result and result2 into **results** list.

```
results = result + result2
if len(results) == 2:
        print(results[0]))
        print(results[1]))
elif 1 > len(results) < 2:
    if "best_score" in str(results):
        print("missing", file2)
    else:
        print("missing", file)
else:
    print("missing", file)
    print("missing", file2)

startD += day
```

What do you think about it?

I will also take into consideration your code with purpose of further learning of python, thanks again!

Comment: @MachuPichy It is in my (personal and subjective) opinion that my answer is simpler, much more readable and possibly also faster (I'm not sure how `glob` compares to `os.walk`). Also, I find the expression `elif 1 > len(results) < 2` really dubious and *unsafe*: if the length is `<1`, then obviously it is also `<2` ?. Also note that `print(1>2<2)` yields `False` while `print((1>2)<2)` is `True`, because a `Boolean` can be implicitly cast to an int (1 or 0), which always is `<2`.

Comment: ... However, what I think you should do is this: if your own answer was the one that solved your problem, then delete this post/question, update the description of your previous post, post your own answer there and accept it (your own). What you've done now is to create two duplicate posts and accepted answers that didn't really solve your problem. We should try to avoid that. If an answer helped you in some way, without solving the problem entirely, you can up-vote it without accepting it!